# How to save a file to ./ssh (mac osx)?

Tags: ssh, elastic-map-reduce

How do I save a file to the ./ssh directory (I am using mac osx). What should I enter at the command line or how else can save a downloaded file to ./ssh?

(For more context, I am using Amazon MapReduce and wish to save the EMR.pem file to ssh.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean `~/.ssh` (a directory `.ssh` in your home directory). In the terminal, run

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh
$ cp ~/Downloads/EMR.pem ~/.ssh/
```

where `~/Downloads/EMR.pem` is the place where you have downloaded the file. The first command creates the `.ssh` directory (which you will probably need), the second one copies the file there. If you want to know more, find any tutorial on `bash` (OSX's default shell).

Alternatively, you can enable showing hidden files and folders in Finder (`.ssh` starts with a dot, which is a convention for hidden files), which will allow you to save any files to `.ssh` directly. In terminal, run

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

This is not recommended, since you rarely need to access hidden folders directly and they will obstruct your view in Finder.